# How to add/show time frame in candlestick chart

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, amcharts

I need to display the time in the x axis along with the date,the demo is http://www.amcharts.com/demos/candlestick-chart/ i use the below code, it only shows the dates in the x axis.i want to show it hour wise instead date wise. My code is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chart;
            var graph;
            var graphType = "candlestick";
            var maxCandlesticks = 100;

            var dataString = "2008-05-02,180.19,181.92,178.55,180.94\n2008-05-01,174.96,180.00,174.86,180.00\n2008-04-30,176.19,180.00,172.92,173.95\n2008-04-29,171.11,175.66,170.25,175.05\n2008-04-28,169.75,173.75,169.13,172.24\n2008-04-25,170.70,171.10,166.42,169.73\n2008-04-24,165.34,169.98,159.19,168.94\n2008-04-23,164.05,164.84,161.08,162.89\n2008-04-22,167.40,168.00,158.09,160.20\n2008-04-21,162.21,168.50,161.76,168.16\n2008-04-18,159.12,162.26,158.38,161.04\n2008-04-17,154.17,156.00,153.35,154.49\n2008-04-16,151.72,154.10,150.62,153.70\n2008-04-15,149.40,149.72,145.72,148.38\n2008-04-14,146.77,149.25,144.54,147.78\n2008-04-11,152.72,153.30,146.40,147.14\n2008-04-10,151.13,155.42,150.60,154.55\n2008-04-09,153.31,153.89,150.46,151.44\n2008-04-08,153.55,156.45,152.32,152.84\n2008-04-07,156.13,159.69,155.11,155.89\n2008-04-04,152.19,154.71,150.75,153.08\n2008-04-03,147.06,153.63,147.00,151.61\n2008-04-02,148.78,151.20,145.85,147.49\n2008-04-01,146.30,149.66,143.61,149.53\n2008-03-31,143.27,145.71,142.52,143.50\n2008-03-28,141.80,144.65,141.60,143.01\n2008-03-27,144.95,145.31,139.99,140.25\n2008-03-26,140.87,145.74,140.64,145.06\n2008-03-25,139.96,143.10,137.33,140.98\n2008-03-24,134.01,140.85,133.64,139.53\n2008-03-20,131.12,133.29,129.18,133.27\n2008-03-19,133.12,134.29,129.67,129.67\n2008-03-18,129.18,133.00,128.67,132.82\n2008-03-17,122.55,128.59,122.55,126.73\n2008-03-14,129.88,130.30,124.20,126.61\n2008-03-13,124.10,129.50,123.00,127.94\n2008-03-12,127.04,128.68,125.17,126.03\n2008-03-11,124.10,127.48,122.00,127.35\n2008-03-10,121.98,123.46,119.37,119.69\n2008-03-07,120.41,122.98,119.05,122.25\n2008-03-06,124.61,127.50,120.81,120.93\n2008-03-05,123.58,125.14,122.25,124.49\n2008-03-04,121.99,124.88,120.40,124.62\n2008-03-03,124.44,125.98,118.00,121.73\n2008-02-29,129.29,130.21,124.80,125.02\n2008-02-28,127.20,132.20,125.77,129.91\n2008-02-27,118.23,123.05,118.09,122.96\n2008-02-26,117.64,121.09,115.44,119.15\n2008-02-25,118.59,120.17,116.66,119.74\n2008-02-22,122.48,122.51,115.87,119.46\n2008-02-21,126.05,126.47,120.86,121.54\n2008-02-20,122.20,124.60,121.68,123.82\n2008-02-19,125.99,126.75,121.44,122.18\n2008-02-15,126.27,127.08,124.06,124.63\n2008-02-14,129.40,130.80,127.01,127.46\n2008-02-13,126.68,129.78,125.63,129.40\n2008-02-12,130.70,131.00,123.62,124.86\n2008-02-11,128.01,129.98,127.20,129.45\n2008-02-08,122.08,125.70,121.60,125.48\n2008-02-07,119.97,124.78,117.27,121.24\n2008-02-06,130.83,131.92,121.77,122.00\n2008-02-05,130.43,134.00,128.90,129.36\n2008-02-04,134.21,135.90,131.42,131.65\n2008-02-01,136.24,136.59,132.18,133.75\n2008-01-31,129.45,136.65,129.40,135.36\n2008-01-30,131.37,135.45,130.00,132.18\n2008-01-29,131.15,132.79,129.05,131.54\n2008-01-28,128.16,133.20,126.45,130.01\n2008-01-25,138.99,139.09,129.61,130.01\n2008-01-24,139.99,140.70,132.01,135.60\n2008-01-23,136.19,140.00,126.14,139.07\n2008-01-22,148.06,159.98,146.00,155.64\n2008-01-18,161.71,165.75,159.61,161.36\n2008-01-17,161.51,165.36,158.42,160.89\n2008-01-16,165.23,169.01,156.70,159.64\n2008-01-15,177.72,179.22,164.66,169.04\n2008-01-14,177.52,179.42,175.17,178.78\n2008-01-11,176.00,177.85,170.00,172.69\n2008-01-10,177.58,181.00,175.41,178.02\n2008-01-09,171.30,179.50,168.30,179.40\n2008-01-08,180.14,182.46,170.80,171.25\n2008-01-07,181.25,183.60,170.23,177.64\n2008-01-04,191.45,193.00,178.89,180.05\n2008-01-03,195.41,197.39,192.69,194.93\n2008-01-02,199.27,200.26,192.55,194.84\n2007-12-31,199.50,200.50,197.75,198.08\n2007-12-28,200.59,201.56,196.88,199.83\n2007-12-27,198.95,202.96,197.80,198.57\n2007-12-26,199.01,200.96,196.82,198.95\n2007-12-24,195.03,199.33,194.79,198.80\n2007-12-21,190.12,193.91,189.89,193.91\n2007-12-20,185.43,187.83,183.33,187.21\n2007-12-19,182.98,184.64,180.90,183.12\n2007-12-18,186.52,187.33,178.60,182.98\n2007-12-17,190.72,192.65,182.98,184.40\n2007-12-14,190.37,193.20,189.54,190.39\n2007-12-13,190.19,192.12,187.82,191.83\n2007-12-12,193.44,194.48,185.76,190.86\n2007-12-11,194.75,196.83,187.39,188.54\n2007-12-10,193.59,195.66,192.69,194.21\n2007-12-07,190.54,194.99,188.04,194.30\n2007-12-06,186.19,190.10,186.12,189.95\n2007-12-05,182.89,186.00,182.41,185.50\n2007-12-04,177.15,180.90,176.99,179.81\n2007-12-03,181.86,184.14,177.70,178.86\n2007-11-30,187.34,187.70,179.70,182.22\n2007-11-29,179.43,185.17,179.15,184.29\n2007-11-28,176.82,180.60,175.35,180.22\n2007-11-27,175.22,175.79,170.01,174.81\n2007-11-26,173.59,177.27,172.35,172.54\n2007-11-23,172.00,172.05,169.75,171.54\n2007-11-21,165.84,172.35,164.67,168.46\n2007-11-20,165.67,171.79,163.53,168.85\n2007-11-19,166.10,168.20,162.10,163.95\n2007-11-16,165.30,167.02,159.33,166.39\n2007-11-15,166.39,169.59,160.30,164.30\n2007-11-14,177.16,177.57,163.74,166.11\n2007-11-13,160.85,170.98,153.76,169.96\n2007-11-12,165.28,167.70,150.63,153.76\n2007-11-09,171.15,175.12,165.21,165.37\n2007-11-08,186.67,186.90,167.77,175.47\n2007-11-07,190.61,192.68,186.13,186.30\n2007-11-06,187.05,192.00,185.27,191.79\n2007-11-05,185.29,188.96,184.24,186.18\n2007-11-02,189.21,189.44,183.49,187.87\n2007-11-01,188.60,190.10,180.00,187.44\n2007-10-31,187.63,190.12,184.95,189.95\n2007-10-30,186.18,189.37,184.73,187.00\n2007-10-29,185.45,186.59,184.70,185.09\n2007-10-26,185.29,185.37,182.88,184.70\n2007-10-25,184.87,185.90,181.66,182.78\n2007-10-24,185.81,187.21,179.24,185.93\n2007-10-23,188.56,188.60,182.76,186.16\n2007-10-22,170.35,174.90,169.96,174.36\n2007-10-19,174.24,174.63,170.00,170.42\n2007-10-18,171.50,174.19,171.05,173.50\n2007-10-17,172.69,173.04,169.18,172.75\n2007-10-16,165.54,170.18,165.15,169.58\n2007-10-15,167.98,169.57,163.50,166.98\n2007-10-12,163.01,167.28,161.80,167.25\n2007-10-11,169.49,171.88,153.21,162.23\n2007-10-10,167.55,167.88,165.60,166.79\n2007-10-09,170.20,171.11,166.68,167.86\n2007-10-08,163.49,167.91,162.97,167.91\n2007-10-05,158.37,161.58,157.70,161.45\n2007-10-04,158.00,158.08,153.50,156.24\n2007-10-03,157.78,159.18,157.01,157.92\n2007-10-02,156.55,158.59,155.89,158.45\n2007-10-01,154.63,157.41,152.93,156.34\n2007-09-28,153.44,154.60,152.75,153.47\n2007-09-27,153.77,154.52,152.32,154.50\n2007-09-26,154.47,155.00,151.25,152.77\n2007-09-25,146.84,153.22,146.82,153.18\n2007-09-24,146.73,149.85,146.65,148.28\n2007-09-21,141.14,144.65,140.31,144.15\n2007-09-20,140.15,141.79,139.32,140.31\n2007-09-19,143.02,143.16,139.40,140.77\n2007-09-18,139.06,142.85,137.83,140.92\n2007-09-17,138.99,140.59,137.60,138.41\n2007-09-14,136.57,138.98,136.20,138.81\n2007-09-13,138.83,139.00,136.65,137.20\n2007-09-12,135.99,139.40,135.75,136.85\n2007-09-11,137.90,138.30,133.75,135.49\n2007-09-10,136.99,138.04,133.95,136.71\n2007-09-07,132.01,132.30,130.00,131.77\n2007-09-06,135.56,137.57,132.71,135.01\n2007-09-05,144.97,145.84,136.10,136.76\n2007-09-04,139.94,145.73,139.84,144.16\n2007-08-31,139.49,139.65,137.41,138.48\n2007-08-30,132.67,138.25,132.30,136.25\n2007-08-29,129.88,134.18,129.54,134.08\n2007-08-28,130.99,132.41,126.63,126.82\n2007-08-27,133.39,134.66,132.10,132.25\n2007-08-24,130.53,135.37,129.81,135.30\n2007-08-23,133.09,133.34,129.76,131.07\n2007-08-22,131.22,132.75,130.33,132.51\n2007-08-21,122.21,128.96,121.00,127.57\n2007-08-20,123.96,124.50,120.50,122.22\n2007-08-17,122.01,123.50,119.82,122.06\n2007-08-16,117.01,118.50,111.62,117.05\n2007-08-15,122.74,124.86,119.65,119.90\n2007-08-14,128.29,128.30,123.71,124.03\n2007-08-13,128.32,129.35,126.50,127.79\n2007-08-10,123.12,127.75,120.30,125.00\n2007-08-09,131.11,133.00,125.09,126.39\n2007-08-08,136.76,136.86,132.00,134.01\n2007-08-07,134.94,137.24,132.63,135.03\n2007-08-06,132.90,135.27,128.30,135.25\n2007-08-03,135.26,135.95,131.50,131.85\n2007-08-02,136.65,136.96,134.15,136.49";
            var chartData = [];

            AmCharts.ready(function () {
                // first parse data string
                parseData();

                // SERIAL CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                chart.pathToImages = "images/";
                chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.categoryField = "date";
                // listen for dataUpdated event ad call "zoom" method then it happens
                chart.addListener('dataUpdated', zoomChart);
                // listen for zoomed event andcall "handleZoom" method then it happens
                chart.addListener('zoomed', handleZoom);

                // AXES
                // category
                var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // as our data is date-based, we set this to true
                categoryAxis.minPeriod = "DD"; // our data is daily, so we set minPeriod to "DD"
                categoryAxis.dashLength = 1;
                categoryAxis.tickLenght = 0;
                categoryAxis.inside = true;

                // value
                var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
                valueAxis.dashLength = 1;
                valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

                // GRAPH
                graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.title = "Price:";
                // as candlestick graph looks bad when there are a lot of candlesticks, we set initial type to "line"
                graph.type = "line";
                // graph colors
                graph.lineColor = "#7f8da9";
                graph.fillColors = "#7f8da9";
                graph.negativeLineColor = "#db4c3c";
                graph.negativeFillColors = "#db4c3c";
                graph.fillAlphas = 1;
                graph.proCandlesticks = true;
                // candlestick graph has 4 fields - open, low, high, close
                graph.openField = "open";
                graph.highField = "high";
                graph.lowField = "low";
                graph.closeField = "close";
                graph.balloonText = "Open:<b>[[open]]</b><br>Low:<b>[[low]]</b><br>High:<b>[[high]]</b><br>Close:<b>[[close]]</b><br>";
                // this one is for "line" graph type
                graph.valueField = "close";

                chart.addGraph(graph);

                // CURSOR
                var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
                chartCursor.valueLineEnabled = true;
                chartCursor.valueLineBalloonEnabled = true;
                chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

                // SCROLLBAR
                var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
                chartScrollbar.scrollbarHeight = 30;
                chartScrollbar.graph = graph; // as we want graph to be displayed in the scrollbar, we set graph here
                chartScrollbar.graphType = "line"; // we don't want candlesticks to be displayed in the scrollbar
                chartScrollbar.gridCount = 4;
                chartScrollbar.color = "#FFFFFF";
                chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

                // WRITE
                chart.write("chartdiv");
            });


            // this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
            function zoomChart() {
                // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
                chart.zoomToIndexes(chartData.length - 50, chartData.length - 1);
            }

            // this methid is called each time the selected period of the chart is changed
            function handleZoom(event) {
                var startDate = event.startDate;
                var endDate = event.endDate;
                document.getElementById("startDate").value = AmCharts.formatDate(startDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
                document.getElementById("endDate").value = AmCharts.formatDate(endDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");

                // as we also want to change graph type depending on the selected period, we call this method
                changeGraphType(event);
            }

            // changes graph type to line/candlestick, depending on the selected range
            function changeGraphType(event) {
                var startIndex = event.startIndex;
                var endIndex = event.endIndex;

                if (endIndex - startIndex > maxCandlesticks) {
                    // change graph type
                    if (graph.type != "line") {
                        graph.type = "line";
                        graph.fillAlphas = 0;
                        chart.validateNow();
                    }
                } else {
                    // change graph type
                    if (graph.type != graphType) {
                        graph.type = graphType;
                        graph.fillAlphas = 1;
                        chart.validateNow();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Parse data
            function parseData() {
                // split data string into array
                var rowArray = dataString.split("\n");
                // loop through this array and create data items
                for (var i = rowArray.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                    var row = rowArray[i].split(",");
                    var dateArray = row[0].split("-");
                    // we have to subtract 1 from month, as months in javascript are zero-based
                    var date = new Date(Number(dateArray[0]), Number(dateArray[1]) - 1, Number(dateArray[2]));
                    var open = row[1];
                    var high = row[2];
                    var low = row[3];
                    var close = row[4];

                    chartData.push({
                        date: date,
                        open: open,
                        high: high,
                        low: low,
                        close: close
                    });
                }
            }

            // this method converts string from input fields to date object
            function stringToDate(str) {
                var dArr = str.split("/");
                var date = new Date(Number(dArr[2]), Number(dArr[1]) - 1, dArr[0]);
                return date;
            }

            // this method is called when user changes dates in the input field
            function changeZoomDates() {
                var startDateString = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
                var endDateString = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
                var startDate = stringToDate(startDateString);
                var endDate = stringToDate(endDateString);
                chart.zoomToDates(startDate, endDate);
            }
        </script>


<div id="chartdiv" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
        <div style="float:right;margin-right:20px;">
            <input onChange="changeZoomDates()" style="width:100px; text-align:center"
            type="text" id="startDate">-
            <input onChange="changeZoomDates()" style="width:100px; text-align:center"
            type="text" id="endDate"></div>
```

how to get the time frame in the chart??

Answer (score 0):

```
    categoryAxis.minPeriod = "hh"; //DD is for days.
```

fff - millisecond, ss - second, mm - minute, hh - hour, DD - day, MM - month, YYYY - year.

Comment: You can use dateFormat to format the dates.
 categoryAxis.dateFormat = "JJ:NN:SS" for hours:mins:secs

https://amcharts.zendesk.com/entries/23272496-Formatting-dates-on-category-axis

Comment: hi,anurag thanks.. i already tried this before upload this qustion... its  working buddy..but i want to show the time frame in the baloon text or in the x axis label like feb1 12:00 02:00 04:00 feb2 01:00 02:00 04:00 in the X axis

Comment: chartAxis.categoryBalloonDateFormat = "JJ:NN:SS";